# Can a List<...> have a count of -1?

Tags: c#, list, count

I'm doing a code reading for an issue, where the following values seems to be equal to 3:

```
Math.Max((List1.Count - List2.Count), 0);
```

Now, normally `List1.Count` cannot be larger than 2, so this would mean that `List2.Count` equals (-1).

Is this even possible? Can a `List` object's `Count` property be equal to -1? If yes, how?

**Edit: where did I get this idea?**
As you might remember from your first programming exercises, we have all got the question "*write a program that takes the sum of a number of positive numbers. You enter those numbers one by one and once you enter "-1" this means that the program must stop taking numbers and show the sum.*", so `-1` is a typical "*default value*", which makes me wonder if there are `List` objects where the `Count` property has a default value, and where that default value equals `-1`.

Comment: You said "normally". I would check your assumption here as it's not possible to get a negative count here.

Comment: If you're observing it have an out of bounds value, you've almost certainly gone wrong somewhere earlier, such as by allowing multiple threads to manipulate it at the same time.

Comment: If your assumption is that list1 is always greater then list2 than you should rather replace that code with an assertion and throw an exception if your assumption isn't met.

Comment: The first thing you should have done is look at `List1.Count` and `List2.Count` separately instead of assuming that you know what one of them is and then believing that the other must be some nonsense value.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,aeb6ba6c11713802; note that `_size` (which corresponds to `Count`) has `0` as a default value.

Comment: For defaults it might help you to use the/look at the `default`method. A `default(Int32)` return 0.

Comment: There's a difference between a "default" value and a "special" value. `0` is a common default value, whereas `-1` is a common special value. Special values are special because they don't exist in real world situations so they can indicate errors and exit conditions. Your edit indicates that you've conflated these concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The `Count` property of a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` cannot be negative (unless you somehow manage to brute-forcely break it using reflection).

Comment: And why not? Decompiler says it's an `int`, so theoretically it can be.

Comment: `Count` is a get-only property.

Comment: @Dominique Lots of things use Int32 for cases where the value would never be negative in the real world. I'm not even sure what a negative value for a list count would mean.

Comment: Try creating an array of negative size. Count just surfaces the size of the inner array of the list. And its an int because not every language allowed to use the framework knows about  unsigned type so the framework more or less nowhere uses unsigned types.

Comment: Theoretically? Yes. Using reflection? Yes. But not in the current implementation.

Comment: The reflection solution would then be a lie. The size of the inner array won't change.

Comment: I've updated my question, explaining where my idea comes from.

Comment: @Dominique: The default value of `Count` is `0`.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you can *hack* the list with a help of **Reflection**.

After consulting [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,aeb6ba6c11713802) (.Net Framework) or [repository](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs) (.Net Core) we can come up with the code:

```
using System.Reflection;
  
...

List<int> list = new List<int>();

list
  .GetType()
  .GetField("_size", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
  .SetValue(list, -1);

// -1
Console.Write(list.Count);
```

But I *really doubt* if anything like this can appear in your code

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zDeJmT)